# How to get a proportion from two variables in a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, data-science, jupyter

Question: "What proportion of the subjects have a lower SBP on the second reading compared to the first?" This is from the nhanes_univariate_practice in the Understanding and Visualizing Data with Python Coursera course.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't see any code in this question. Maybe you should rather ask on similar portal [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Need code and files in order to help you.